# iPhone & Core Data - Removing NSManagedObject?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm trying to remove a managed object context, but instead of removing the object itself it sets all instant variables to null.
Am I doing anything wrong while deleting an instant of NSManagedObjectContext?

```
@implementation MyManagedObject

- (BOOL)submitToServer
{
     if (/*submitted successfully*/)
     {
          return YES;
     }
     else
     {
          [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:self];
          return NO;
     }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must call `[self.managedObjectContext save:nil]` after `deleteObject` for the delete to be committed to the persistent store. Read more about [deleting a managed object](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001654-SW1).